# Python: Add unique values from a CSV column to list

Tags: python, csv

I'm going through a CSV that has a list of cargo movements between various ports, and I'd like to take all the unique values for the ports into a new list.

Currently, I have the below, it adds every value under the 'Origin Ports' column, how can I make sure it adds just the unique values under that column? Thank you.

```py
import csv

CSV_FILE = "Bitumen2021Exports.csv"

ports = []
  
with open(CSV_FILE, encoding="utf-8-sig") as bitumen_csv:
    bitumen_reader = csv.DictReader(bitumen_csv)
    for port in bitumen_reader:
        ports.append(port['ORIGIN PORT'])

print(ports)
```

The data in the CSV looks like below:
[image]

Comment: Appending to something you're iterating over is not a good idea. Please show more source data and expected output

Comment: Is this a typo? Aren't you supposed to do `ports.append()` rather than append to the reader itself? Side note, to get unique values you probably want to make `ports` a set rather than a list.

Comment: @JCaesar - the data is pretty much the same throughout the CSV if that's what you mean? I'd like to return a list with the unique values such that ports = ['port a', 'port b', ..., 'port z'] etc

Comment: @shriakhilc woops yes sorry! should indeed be `ports.append()` - okay i'll try having a look at sets, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also skip handling the "uniqueness logic" and use Python's **set**, which only allows unique elements:

```py
import csv

CSV_FILE = "Bitumen2021Exports.csv"

ports = set()
  
with open(CSV_FILE, encoding="utf-8-sig") as bitumen_csv:
    bitumen_reader = csv.DictReader(bitumen_csv)
    for port in bitumen_reader:
          ports.add(port['ORIGIN PORTS'])

print(ports)
```

Ports, a set, is an iterable, or just convert to a list if you need, `list(ports)`.

Answer (score 1):

One way based on your code:

```
import csv

CSV_FILE = "Bitumen2021Exports.csv"

ports = []
  
with open(CSV_FILE, encoding="utf-8-sig") as bitumen_csv:
    bitumen_reader = csv.DictReader(bitumen_csv)
    for port in bitumen_reader:
        if port['ORIGIN PORTS'] not in ports:
              ports.append(port['ORIGIN PORTS'])

print(ports)
```

Another way is to import the csv into a `pandas` df and use `column.unique()`.

Comment: Answer makes sense, thank you! Got the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

A minor variation to show how one could use a set comprehension:

```
import csv

CSV_FILE = "Bitumen2021Exports.csv"
  
with open(CSV_FILE, encoding="utf-8-sig") as bitumen_csv:
    ports = {port['ORIGIN PORT'] for port in csv.DictReader(bitumen_csv)}
    print(ports)
```